# PHP - display function output for parameters for func_get_args()

Tags: php, function

I have this function

```
<?php

function rawInfo($secretWord, $args){
    $args = func_get_args();
    return $args;
}
 $args = ['arg_1', 'arg_2'];
print_r(rawInfo('secret_word',$args));
```

When I return the variable I only want `arg_1` and `arg_2` to appear. I don't want 'secret_word'. The above output gives me

```
   (
[0] => secret_word
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => arg_1
        [1] => arg_2
    )
```

)

The only way I managed to hide `secret_word` is by doing `unset($arg[0])`. I prefer not to use this method.

Comment: Do you have to have `secret_word` in the array?

Comment: I've updated my question to be more clear `$args = ['arg_1', 'arg_2'];`
`print_r(rawInfo('secret_word',$args));`

Comment: Okay..do you have to pass `secret_word` to the function? Just trying to get an idea of your scope more.

Comment: @ACDC: You could simply return $args? Or am I not understanding something?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to accomplish here. If you want rawInfo to just return arg_1 and arg_2, just return $args. If you want $args to be "arg_1" and "arg_2" just don't change it. If this is a part of a larger application, it might be helpful to have some documented code to help us understand what the application is to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not

PHP document:

```
Gets an array of the function's argument list.
```

This method return all of arguments

By the way, you have too use `array_shift` or `unset`

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to accomplish here.

If you want rawInfo to just return arg_1 and arg_2, just return $args.

If you want $args to be "arg_1" and "arg_2" just don't change $args.

If this is a part of a larger application, it might be helpful to have some documented code to help us understand what the application is to do here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [func_get_arg(int $position)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php) to return only specific argument. In your case it would be `func_get_arg(1)`

```
<?php

function rawInfo($secretWord, $args){
    $args = func_get_arg(1);
    return $args;
}
$args = ['arg_1', 'arg_2'];
print_r(rawInfo('secret_word',$args));
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense why you are passing in three parameters into a function with two arguments. This will generate an error in PHP. If you need to pass in `arg_1` and `arg_2` you could do it through an array.

```
<?php

function rawInfo($secretWord, $args){
    $args = func_get_args();
    return $args;
}

print_r(rawInfo('secret_word', ['arg_1', 'arg_2']));

?>
```

This will generate the following output:

```
Array ( [0] => secret_word [1] => Array ( [0] => arg_1 [1] => arg_2 ) )
```

It looks like you are trying to get multiple arguments passed in and assigned to one variable $args. Passing in `arg_1` and `arg_2` in an array like so will help you return an array from the function `rawInfo()`.